# createRoot(...): Target container is not a DOM element?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

createRoot(...): Target container is not a DOM element? What need to change? 'It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.', 'It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.','It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.'

App.test.tsx

```
import { createRoot } from "react-dom/client";
import App from "./App";


it('renders without crashing', () => {
  const root = createRoot(document.getElementById("root") as HTMLElement);
  render(<App/>)
});
```

index.tsx

```
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import App from './App';

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root') as HTMLElement);

root.render (
              <App/>     
)
```

App.tsx

```
import React from 'react';
import './Reset.css';
import './App.css';
import Main from './components/Main/Main';
import HeaderContainer from './components/Header/HeaderContainer';
import { connect, Provider } from 'react-redux';
import Preloader from './components/common/Preloader/Preloader';
import { initializeApp } from './redux/appReducer';
import { HashRouter, Route, Routes } from 'react-router-dom';
import store, { AppStateType } from './redux/redux-store';
import Footer from './components/Footer/Footer';
import GuestPage from './components/common/GuestPage/GuestPage';
import ContainerLogin from './components/common/Login/ContainerLogin';


type MapStateType = {
  isAuth: boolean
  initializedApp: boolean
}

type DispatchPropsType = {
  initializeApp: () => void
}

class SocialApp extends React.Component<MapStateType & DispatchPropsType> {

  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.initializeApp()
  }

  render () {
    if (!this.props.initializedApp) { 
      return <Preloader/>
    } else return (
      <>
          <HeaderContainer/>
          <div className='main__wrapper'>
            <Routes>            
                <Route path="/*" element={<Main/>}/>
                <Route path="/guestpage" element={<GuestPage/>}/>
                <Route path="/login" element={<ContainerLogin/>}/>  
            </Routes>
            </div>
          <Footer/>
      </>
    )
  }
}
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

const mapStateToProps = (state: AppStateType) => ({
  initializedApp: state.app.initialized,
  isAuth: state.auth.isAuth
})

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch: any) => ({
  initializeApp: () => {
    dispatch(initializeApp())
  },
})


let AppContainer = connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(SocialApp);


const App: React.FC<{}> = () => {
    return  (<HashRouter>
              <Provider store={store}>
                <div className='App__wrapper'>
                  <AppContainer/>
                </div>
              </Provider>
            </HashRouter>)
}

export default App
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the element name you define in `index.tsx` (e.g., 'root') is also specified in the body of your `index.html` file. For example:

index.tsx

```
...
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root') as HTMLElement);
...
```

index.html

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```